# Analytical solution to a fourth order Partial Differential equation in polar coordinates

Tags: pde

I want to solve the following PDE fourth order Partial Differential equation in polar coordinates (equation is given in the image file):
[equation of 4th order pde](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXNXg.png)

I will highly appreciate if anyone help me.

Thanks,
Abrar

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are a programming site, not a math site.

Comment: Try separation of variables.